# ¿Se puede iniciar una aplicación con PowerShell e interactuar con ella? Guardar proyecto, cerrarla

Tags: windows, script, cmd, powershell

Tengo la siguiente duda después de leer sobre PowerShell y ver que se puede abrir el Microsoft Word desde la consola Powershell y desde la misma abrir un nuevo documento, guardarlo, escribir en él, etc. En el post donde lo vi utilizaba comando `Start-Transcript`

Mi pregunta es si se puede hacer lo mismo pero con otras aplicaciones que no sean de Microsoft, por ejemplo con alguna aplicación de diseño o alguna aplicación tipo Notepad++ o algo así. Lo único que me interesa es acceder a esa aplicación y guardar el proyecto actual, y poder así hacer este proceso automáticamente.

Saludos.

Comment: Eliminaré la etiqueta de "bash" (aunque eso fue el anzuelo que me trajo aquí ;) )

Answer (score 1):

El cmdlet `Start-Process` puede realizar algo relacionado con lo que pides, por ejemplo, si quieres abrir un archivo con notepad++ puedes ejecutar algo así.

```
Start-Process notepad++ .\archivo
```

o un poco verboso.

```
Start-Process -FilePath notepad++ .\archivo
```

[Aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6) puedes ver su documentación.

Comment: ¿Y guardar este archivo sin necesidad de hacerlo el usuario?

Comment: Supongo que dependería de 1) Las opciones que el programa tenga vía consola. 2) Si es que existen plugins para ese programa que quieras usar, 3) Si quieres que sea puro texto, puedes usar algo de tipo `Get-Content <archivo> | Out-File <archivo>`

Comment: Por cierto, sería interesante que compartieras el post que mencionaste en tu pregunta.